# Realm RLMArray is nil at runtime

Tags: objective-c, swift, realm

I'm using the Realm Objective-C framework for a Swift project (as I need it to work for iOS 7) and get a runtime `unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value` error on a `RLMArray` field.

Models look like this

```
class A: RLMObject {
    dynamic var name = ""
}

class B: RLMObject {
    dynamic var category = ""
    var items = RLMArray(objectClassName: A.className())
}
```

And doing

```
let a = A() // existing (saved) Realm object
let b = B() // existing (saved) Realm object
let realm = RLMRealm.defaultRealm()
realm.beginWriteTransaction()
b.items.addObject(a) // <- error
realm.commitWriteTransaction()
```

raises the runtime error.

I'm using Xcode 6.4 and Swift 1.2.

Any ideas why this is happening?

Comment: Can you try marking the `items` property as being `dynamic` ?
Additionally, seeing the entire backtrace at the time of the crash would be helpful!

Comment: Real Objective-C ? Why don't use Real Swift library ?

Comment: @segiddins Tried using `dynamic`. It raises a different error.
@Burn I need the Objective-C framework so it's compatible with iOS 7. The Swift framework only works for iOS 8.

Comment: @segiddins  You were right. Adding `dynamic` to `items` fixes the issue. When I previously tried this, it triggered an error on a Realm-related line. However, the error was due to something in my code which I mistakenly attributed to Realm. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

As pointed out by @segiddins, the fix is to add `dynamic` to `items`.